# How to pass dynamic redirectUrl to Azure appregistration auth process (.NET framework)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, routes

I have a website that can only be accessed after authentication. We rely on the Azure AppRegistrations to execute this auth process. What happens now is the following:

- A user submits a URL where the base is my website (lets say 'https://www.mywebsite.com/specific_page').
- The website starts and lets the user authenticate via Azure, passing a return URL (https://www.mywebsite.com).
- After authentication, the user gets redirected to the startpage on https://www.mywebsite.com, instead of the URL he gave to start with

Is there any way to get the URL the user submitted in the Global.asax of an ASP.NET 3.7 application? Or is there any other way I am missing?

Thanks for your reply...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get the URL the user submitted in the Global.asax
> of an ASP.NET 3.7 application? Or is there any other way I am missing?

When you submit request to Azure AD for login, you can add a `state` parameter to the request. Whatever you pass in this parameter gets returned back to you on successful login.

What you can do is pass the landing page specified by the user in state and redirect the user to that page after successful login.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @Gaurav Mantri. The problem i'm facing is: I can't seem to get the URL the visitor provided (so https://mywebsite.com/somepage), so I can't add in to the state parameter... Have you got any idea how I could get this entire URL (not only the base) in Global.asax or Owin Startup-class?

Comment: You should be able to make use of HTTP referer to get this information. Can you please try that?